# Images not displaying in Ionic App Lab preview

Tags: html, ionic-framework

When I preview [this app](https://github.com/hack-r/ionic) using `ionic serve --lab` the images display fine on the homepage and menu, but not on the "About Us" page for some reason. The image being displayed for each one of the "leaders" in the "About Us" page is the exact same image ("Alberto.png") displaying properly near the bottom of home.html

```
<ion-view view-title="About Us">
  <ion-content>
      <div class="card">
  <div class="item item-divider">
    Our History
  </div>
    <div><p>Started in 2010, Ristorante con Fusion quickly established itself as a culinary icon par excellence in Hong Kong. With its unique brand of world fusion cuisine that can be found nowhere else, it enjoys patronage from the A-list clientele in Hong Kong.  Featuring four of the best three-star Michelin chefs in the world, you never know what will arrive on your plate the next time you visit us.

    The restaurant traces its humble beginnings to The Frying Pan, a successful chain started by our CEO, Mr. Peter Pan, that featured for the first time the world's best cuisines in a pan.
    </p></div>      
      </div>
      <div class="card">
          <div class="item item-divider">
          <b>Corporate Leadership</b>    
          </div>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="leader in leaders" class="list-inset">
          <div class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap">
               <img ng-src="{{baseURL+leader.image}}" alt="">
                <br><b>{{leader.name}}</b>
                <br><b>{{leader.designation}}</b>
                <p>{{leader.description}}</p>
            </ion-item>  
          </div>
      </div>            
      <!-- below is a deprecated alternate attempt>
         <ion-list type="list-inset"> 
          <ion-item ng-repeat="leader in leaders" class="list-inset">
                        <div class="item item-body item-text-wrap">
              <img ng-src="{{baseURL+leader.image}}" alt="">      
              <br> {{leader.name}} 
              <br> {{leader.abbr}} 
              <br> {{leader.designation}} 
              <br> {{leader.description}}
              </div>
          </ion-item>      
      </ion-list>
     <-->
  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

It *should* look like this:
[image: Goal]